# Getting a typeError for my password AFTER failed login attempt

Tags: javascript

Once i register on my site, I can login fine and logout fine, and if I don't put anything into the login fields, it throws my error saying a password and email is required and i can reload the login page fine, But if i try to log in with a incorrect password, the error for that throws and says incorrect email or password, BUT once i try to click back to the login page or ANY other page on my site, in my console it says

throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of null

it says the typeError is on the bcrypt.compare line.

```
userSchema.statics.authenticate = function(email, password, callback){
    User.findOne({email: email})
    .exec(function(error, user){
        if(error){
            callback(error)
        }else if(!user){
        const err = new Error('User not found.')    
        err.status = 401
        callback(err)
        }
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function(error, result){
            if(result === true){
                return callback(null, user)
            }else{
                return callback()
            }
        })
    })

}
```

This is my login route

```
router.post('/login', (req, res, next)=>{
  if(req.body.email && req.body.password){

    User.authenticate(req.body.email, req.body.password, function(error, user){
      if( error || !user){
        const err = new Error("Email or password is incorrect.")
        err.status = 401
        next(err)
      }else{

        req.session.userId = user._id;
        res.redirect('/profile')
      }
    });

  }else{
    const err= new Error('Email and Password required.')
    err.status = 401
    next(err)
  }

})
```

Everything works great, the only time it crashes the server/site is when I try to log in with an INCORRECT  password, then it throws the error and then after throwing the error the site crashes. If I don't put a email or password, it throws the error for that and continues to work fine, and again I can log in with the correct email and password, log out and register just fine.

Node/express is new to me, so forgive me for any rookie mistakes. I'm trying to learn how to properly debug in express/Node.js.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Could you post your front end flow, when you're logging in, are you using an ajax request or reloading the entire page? This seems like your form is being resubmitted at some point with invalid values because of which its crashing.

Comment: @JudeFernandes Thank you for the help but mbojko answered for me and everything works now!

Answer (score 0):

The problematic line will be executed whether `user` is defined or not (and accessing `undefined.password` will crash the script). You can guard it with an `else`:

```
        }else if(!user){
           const err = new Error('User not found.')    
           err.status = 401
           callback(err)
        } else {
           bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function(error, result){
```